# Windows 7 Explorer Context menu handler

Tags: windows, shell, contextmenu

I want to build a context menu entry for renaming multiple files selected in Windows explorer at once with predefined hardcoded rules (for example rename "01 music tilte.mp3" to "music title.mp3" by always scanning for the first valid character and cut the front).

I am on Windows 7 64bit and have experience in Excel VBA and experience in programming C command line applications in the IDE CodeBlocks.

My entry should work the following way:

a) Select an unlimited number of files in Windows explorer with different file types and Unicode names

b) Call the context menu entry

c) The files are renamed and are still selected in Windows explorer

1) The details "unlimited number of files", "Unicode names" and "still selected" hold me off using simple Registry entries, so I have to use one of the following methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd758091.aspx, am I right?

While browsing https://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ I found out that I won't be able to do it in C but the guides there are somewhat outdated.

2) Since "outdated guide" and "have to learn a new programming language" is a mean combination I am asking you to recommend me a guide or book which helps with my context menu entry while being as related as possible to my C knowledge but first of all working with Windows 7 64bit?

Edit: My new insights:

I have found guides which teach how you can do this
With Plain C: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C?fid=285767&fr=26#DLL
With Plain C++: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/583726/Writing-a-shell-extension-in-plain-Cplusplus

Browsing the two guides I learned that the industry standard seems to be the ATL framework (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ATLShellExtContextMenuHandl-e5c5fc23) with C++ at Microsoft Visual Studio.

Sadly I haven't found a written guide which teaches "ATL - necessary COM - context menus" completely but I have found a commercial video guide (https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-context-menu-shell-extensions-cplusplus?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=1082108) which allegdly teaches this.

3) You are welcome to correct my "new insights".
4) If you know a good written guide for "ATL - necessary COM - context menus" I would be pleased to hear from you.

First of all I will start with learning C++ because it seems to be the right language for achieving my goal.

Comment: Have a look for C++ and COM tutorials. Although COM can be done with C, it needlessly complicates things. Also [OldNewThing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing) is a valuable resource for all shell-related things.

Comment: While researching further I have learned that you only need a fraction of COM knowlegde, also see my "new insights" at my question.